# Display div once scroll trigger passed?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious.  I have a simple goal of making a div visible once the user scrolls past a certain point on the page.  I've searched stack and found multiple solutions, the most basic of which looks like this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $(".linkbar").show();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $(".linkbar").hide();
});
```

That solution appears to have worked for everyone but for some reason, my setup doesn't like the `>` in `.scrolltop() > 200`.

UPDATE...

I'm sorry guys.  I knew it was something obvious.  I simply hadn't bracketed the script with script> and /script>.  Of course I realize this 10 seconds after hitting submit with my question.

Comment: The `.scrollTop() > 200` refers to the scroll size of your window... Are you sure that your window is at least 200px in height?

Answer (score 0):

Simply posting this to close the question.

The editor didn't like the > because I hadn't opened and closed the script.  The shockingly obvious solution is this...

```
<script>
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $(".linkbar").show();
}
});
$(document).ready(function(){        
$(".linkbar").hide();
});
</script>
```